# Excel add url with increment in all rows of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how can run a function to add an url in every row for a column where there are only images in every row, in which for every row the number at the end of the file name would increment by 2 and to get the file from the current directory of the excel file, something like this:

```
'currdir\imagenes\image001.png' 
'currdir\imagenes\image003.png' 
'currdir\imagenes\image005.png'
```

And so on...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a formula:

```
="'currdir\imagenes\image" & text((2*row())-1, "000") & ".png'"
```

And just copy that down your rows (assuming we are starting in row 1 here, otherwise you'll have to adjust that formula.

To make this dynamically use the path of the current workbook you can use the `Cell()` formula with some `Left()` and `Find()` string manipulation:

```
="'" & LEFT(CELL("filename", A1), FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1) & "imagenes\image" & text((2*row())-1, "000") & ".png'"
```

Comment: By get the file from the current directory i mean, that if the excel sheet is in a folder, i would like the url to direct like this: "currentfolder\imagenes\image.png" so that it can work in every computer. I've been trying to use a vbs macro to change every image in the column to urls, like this:

Comment: Sub ReplacePictures()
    For Each wShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If (wShape.Type = 13) Then
            wShape.TopLeftCell = "url"
            wShape.Delete
        End If
    Next wShape
End Sub

Comment: Updated the answer with a formula to use the current workbook's path

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer but whenever i try to use the formula in my cells, excel shows this on the cells: #####.

Comment: What about if you break it up `=text((2*row())-1, "000")` and `=LEFT(CELL("filename", A1), FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)` Do those give you reasonable outputs?

Comment: Which one, of those two formulas, shows ` #¿NOMBRE?`?

Comment: In order for that `Cell("Filename")` formula to work correctly, the workbook must be saved. Otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Hello, both of them show that and the document is indeed saved. :-/

Comment: Are you using a locale that requires semi-colons to separate formula parameters? like: `=text((2*row())-1; "000")` Other than that, I have no idea why such a simple formula would fail.

Comment: I'm not an expert in using excel with formulas but i think i'm inserting them right :-/ It should be working...